# Can I implement iterator in binary search tree without stack?

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator

Suppose I have binary search tree. Each node have two pointers to children and no pointer to the parent.

Is there efficient way to implement iterator without using stack or queue?

By efficient I mean to be able to find next element in O(1) complexity.

Comment: I guess that even using stack the best you can get is O(1) _amortized_ complexity.

Comment: Morris traversal ?

Comment: @vivek_23 nice one, but not doing any good in my case.

Comment: @Nick The next successor for a node is tricky to obtain however if you wish to store more data than just 2 children for a node, then there are options.

Comment: @Nick, why exactly is Morris traversal not a candidate?

Comment: @trincot because it is modifies the tree.

Comment: If that is a requirement, then that should be mentioned in your question. But note that with a Morris traversal the tree will be back in its original state once the iterator has been completely consumed.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the case of a perfect tree with height *h*. When the iterator is at the first node (the leftmost leaf), it will need to remember somehow by which internal nodes it arrived at this node, because in one of the next steps it will need to yield the values in those nodes (and their right subtrees). As there are no parent node pointers, this information is not readily available and must be stored somewhere.

No matter how this path is memorised (a list of internal nodes, or a list of directions, like left-left-left-left, possibly stored compactly in bit-representation), the theoretical size of this storage is O(h).

As noted in comments below, storing only directions will require to walk down the path again from the root at each step in the iteration. Alternatively you could memorise the last visited value, and use binary search to find the next node. If all values in the tree are unique, then the memory size of the actual values will have at least the same order of magnitude as a compact path representation (bitwise left-left-left...), so either way (storing the path, or the last visited value) the storage requirements are similar.

Now, as soon as you put some limit on the size of the tree, there is of course no more sense in talking about space (or time) complexity. For instance, if a tree is never going to have a height of more than 64, then the current path can be represented in a 64-bit unsigned integer, with maybe some additional small integer to denote the current size of that path.

As the number of atoms in the observable universe is estimated at 2<sup>250</sup>, you could work with that as well, and use a 256-bit unsigned integer instead (two longs). Computer memory will never be capable of storing a perfect tree of that height any way.

Comment: What do you do with a list of left/right directions? I don't think you can implement an amortized O(1) iterator with that...

Comment: You could always keep in your iterator the last key iterated - that's O(1) storage, and allows you to know exactly what's the next node to visit. But then without a parent pointer you still have to start from the root, so it will take more than O(1) steps.

Comment: @ciamej, of course I agree. I was focussing on space complexity, and your second comment makes sense. Either way, there is no way without mutating the tree to get both time and space complexity at O(1).

Comment: One more comment. If storing the value is considered O(1) space, then the bitwise path representation should also be considered O(1), at least when the tree holds unique values. The number of different values in a perfect tree is 2^h - 1, and that is the same as the number of path representations...

Answer (score 1):

To summarize: the iterator should have a small size (independent of tree size), and there's also no additional information in the tree nodes. Also, the tree can be unbalanced in any way.

In that case, the answer must be **no**, from a pigeon-hole principle. The problem is that until you've processed the last node, there's no way to predict how many nodes remain, and how they are related. There's literally an infinite number of options, but the directly available information is finite.

Comment: I'm not convinced by that logic (although I believe the answer *no* is correct). You don't touch on the O(1) requirement, and without that requirement it is reasonably easy to construct an appropriate iterator.

Comment: @ciamej: The O(1) requirement mirrors the "**directly** available information". You can always go back to the root and rebuild a stack that you didn't store in the iterator object, but that's an O(log N) process to gather information which isn't directly available in the iterator.

Comment: re: "directly available information" - I haven't met such term before. I would rather analyze it in terms of asymptotic memory and processing steps bounds. O(1) memory and O(1) processing steps impossible. O(1) memory and O(log n) processing steps possible (for a balanced tree). O(log n) memory and amortized O(1) processing steps possible (again for a balanced tree).

Comment: I checked how they do it in `std::set` Red Black tree - there they have pointer to the parent.

Comment: @Nick: Red-Black trees are of course special cases of binary trees, with an occasional rebalance. That limits how unbalanced a tree can become, and therefore how far you need to search for a successor.

Comment: @MSalters - well this is not related to the iterator. search and iterating red-black tree is no different than normal search tree.

Comment: @Nick: The search algorithm isn't different, but the complexity is. Red-black trees has search complexity O(log N), but the bound for ordinary binary trees is O(N).